# How can I generate a snake shape with texts in c++?

Tags: design-patterns

Let's say, I want to print total `m` no of lines and the turning point is after every `n` no. of lines.

```
w
 w
  w
   w
    w
   w
  w
 w
w
 w
  w
   w
    w
   w
  w
 w
w
```

The value of `m`, `n`, and the text(`w`) will be taken from the user.

This is what I am done so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int m, n;  // total number of lines: m, turning points at interval: n, text: a 
    string a;
    cin>>m>>n>>a;

        int i=1;
    for(int k=1; k<=n/2; k++){
        cout<<setw(i)<<a<<endl;
        i++;
    }
    int j=(n/2)+1;
    for(int k=(n/2)+1; k<=n; k++){
        cout<<setw(j)<<a<<endl;
        j--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main(){

    int lines_number;
    int turning_point;
    std::string text;

    std::cin >> lines_number >> turning_point >> text;

    int inc_dec = 1;
    for(int line = 0, spaces = 1; line < lines_number; line++, spaces += inc_dec)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(spaces) << text << std::endl;

        if((spaces == turning_point) || (spaces == 1 && inc_dec < 0))
        {
            inc_dec *= -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is what I was looking for.